# Fluent NHibernate mapping a Dictionary of self-references

Tags: dictionary, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I understand there are several related questions and I have looked at many of them but the solutions don't seem to work in my case.

I am using NH 2.1 with Fluent (yes it's an older version, but it's a common denominator across several related projects and it will take some work to upgrade), and I'm basically mapping an FSM; the user of this system is presented with questions, one at a time, to which there are usually two or more answers from which they choose. Their answer leads to the next question, which can vary depending on the answer given.

This creates a domain something like this (slightly sanitized):

```
public class Question
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the "questionnaire" Template in which this Question is asked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The template.</value>
    public virtual QuestionnaireTemplate Template { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a string to be displayed to the user containing the question to answer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The question.</value>
    public virtual string QuestionText { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a Question representing the previous question in the questionnaire.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The previous question.</value>
    public virtual Question PreviousQuestion { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a Dictionary of Questions, each representing the question that should follow given a specified answer to the current question.
    /// Null Values for Keys in this Dictionary represent endpoints of the questionnaire.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The next questions.</value>
    public virtual IDictionary<string, Question> NextQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

So, I am required by the domain to create a self-referencing table; a simple foreign key to the previous question, and a many-to-many "QuestionAnswers" table keyed by Question and Answer, containing the key of the next Question to ask given that particular Answer to the current Question.

Here's my mapping so far, based on at least one answer to a related question of Dictionary mapping:

```
public TourQuestionMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Template);
        Map(x => x.QuestionText);

        References(x => x.PreviousQuestion);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.NextQuestions)
            .Table("QuestionAnswers")
            .ParentKeyColumns.Add("QuestionId", "Answer")
            .ChildKeyColumn("NextQuestionId")
            .AsMap("Answer")
            .Cascade.All();
    }
```

... but when I try to export a schema based on this, I get an error regarding an association to an unmapped entity KeyValuePair, which would indicate that I'm trying to use the wrong collection construct in NH. I'm not well-experienced with collection mapping other than basic HasMany() mappings of another mapped entity.

Here's the basic schema I'm after:

```
Question
   QuestionId (int, PK, non-nullable)
   TemplateId (int, FK to Template, not nullable, not an issue AFAIK)
   QuestionText (string, not nullable)
   PreviousQuestion (int, FK to Question, nullable, also not an issue AFAIK)

QuestionAnswer (my problem child)
   QuestionId (int, PK, FK to Question, not nullable)
   Answer (string PK, key of Dictionary in domain, not nullable)
   NextQuestionId (int, FK to Question, nullable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you define Answer separately and provide a mapping for it?

Something Like

```
class Answer
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string AnswerText { get; set; }
  public virtual Question NextQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

Now Question becomes

```
class Question
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionnaireTemplate Template { get; set; }
    public virtual string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public virtual Question PreviousQuestion { get; set; }
    private List<Answer> answers
    //Map this
    public virtual IList<Answer> AnswerList { get return answers; }
    public virtual IDictionary<string, Answer> Answers {get return answers.ToDictionary(a => a.AnswerText)}
}
```

I just think this simplifies the mapping.

Comment: This is feasible, if not ideal. If someone else doesn't come up with a way to map this as-is you'll get the check; for now, +1.